# Eevee autosmooth

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I am making an eye in 2.8 and came across a problem with shading. Mesh edges reflected the inside and whole thing appeared flat even with smooth shading applied.

[image]

[image]

Here is the same mesh subdivided 6 times.

[image]

Looks bad and has a lot of unnecessary faces. So I used Autosmooth which managed it pretty nicely but still left me with some weird effect where the shadow is cast. I tried changing the size of my lamp with no result.

Blend file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cann't reproduce. If you place just UV sphere near eye - it's looks with the same reflection? Interestion to know how mesh looks and light setup.

Comment: @tdhster I've attached blend file

Comment: Your blend mode is set to **opaque** by the way

Comment: @Michal, it's displacement on material setup as answered below. https://imgur.com/R2bZBWf subsurf it 2, with multiply displacement node entry on 0.01 (or disconnected). Just scale down aplitude or use displace modifier after subsurf.

Comment: @tdhster I've done as you said and the reflection is much better but still a bit distorted. https://i.imgur.com/GJAcbwF.png

Comment: @Michal https://imgur.com/MmEFsPE with added multiply node beween existed with 0.01. Also smooth shade on.

Answer (score 0):

I think your displacement map is giving this weird pixelated swirls around the eye. Also, why is it connected to an image without a file? Is that how you intended it to be?

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong but I get this effect even on a sphere with no material. blob:https://imgur.com/dd7396f3-c2cd-433e-ba92-2ac4b6f19924 No file in image node was accidental.